# What is an alternative term for "Swiss army knife"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What is an alternative term for *Swiss army knife*?

As in a general multi-purpose tool.  It is a word that everybody understands, but I would like to know some alternatives.

Clarification:
The term *Swiss army knife* is often used to express a multi-purpose, versatile tool outside the contexts of knives or armies.

- The Swiss army knife for writing books.
- Perl is the Swiss army knife among programming languages.
- Swiss army knife of codecs (Google's search entry completion).

I think that "multi-tool" or "one stop shop" are adequate alternative, maybe there are more?

Comment: Thank you for your answers and images but it were not the answers I was hoping for. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might say *multi-tool*.

> A multi-tool (or multitool) is any one of a range of portable, versatile hand tools that combines several individual functions in a single unit.
> -- [from Wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Multi-tool)

Answer (score 4):

*[Pocketknife](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pocketknife)* is the most common term for this type of tool.  All Swiss Army knives are pocketknives:

[image: Pocketknife]

But *multi-tool* would work, too, especially if the tool in question is not a pocketknife:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the pics, really helpful especially "for a word that everybody understands"

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia seems to give the answer quite clearly when it defines what a [Swiss army knife is:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_Army_knife)

> A Swiss Army knife .... is a pocket knife or multi-tool manufactured by Victorinox AG or Wenger SA.